# Girdlayout for Squares of different size in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout, node-webkit

I am developing an app (node-webkit) that shows a number of squares (tiles) in a kind of GridLayout. The  tiles are all the same size. When the get clicked, the double theri width and height to show more information. 
It currently looks like this, when one tile is opened.
[image]

What I want to achieve is, to get a grid Layout similiar to this: 
[image]

I am using Bootstrap v.3 for my Layout. The current html looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group row tilecontainer ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude="" delay="500">
        <!-- ngRepeat: info in project.infos -->
    <div class="tile ng-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-repeat="info in project.infos">
            <!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
        <ng-include src="'/html/templates/info_small.html'" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="sq-wrapper ng-scope col-xs-2 small" ng-class="open ? 'col-xs-4 medium' : 'col-xs-2 small'">
            <div class="info-small" ng-click="addInfoData(info, !open || active)" style="overflow:hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
                <!-- ===============
                    Small Look
                ================ -->
                <span class="info-title ng-binding" ng-click="toggle()" ng-hide="open || active">info1</span>


                <!-- ===============
                    Medium Look
                ================ -->
                <div ng-hide="!open || active" class="ng-hide">
                    <div class="row" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 label-input medium center ng-pristine ng-valid" style="text-decoration: underline;" ng-model="info.title">
                    </div>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: d in info.data --><div ng-repeat="d in info.data" class="row ng-scope" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 label-input ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="d.key" ng-blur="deleteDataIfEmpty(d, info.data)">
                        <input class="col-xs-5 label-input ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="d.value" ng-blur="deleteDataIfEmpty(d, info.data)">
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: d in info.data --><div ng-repeat="d in info.data" class="row ng-scope" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 label-input ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="d.key" ng-blur="deleteDataIfEmpty(d, info.data)">
                        <input class="col-xs-5 label-input ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="d.value" ng-blur="deleteDataIfEmpty(d, info.data)">
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: d in info.data -->

                    <div style="width:100%; height:5px;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </ng-include>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: info in project.infos -->
```

The Squares are styled via:

```
.sq-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 45%;
}

.sq-wrapper.small {
    padding-bottom: 15%;
}

.sq-wrapper.medium {
    padding-bottom: 30%;
}


.sq-wrapper > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}

.sq-wrapper.small .sq-wrapper.medium> * {
    position:absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Does anybody know, how to align the small tiles in just two rows, while showing the big tile with a kind of 'colspan=2' & 'rowspan=2' ?